# Create script element with VanillaJS from string which executes

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I get the string:

```
'<script class="heyo">document.write("hello")<\/script>'
```

I must create with VanillaJS an inline script element.

Is there a way to trigger the script execution?

Works but too complicated:

```js
const scriptString = '<script class="heyo">document.write("hello")<\/script>';

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', scriptString);

const pseudoScript = document.body.querySelector('.heyo');

const newScriptEl = document.createElement('script');
[...pseudoScript.attributes].forEach(attr => {
    newScriptEl.setAttribute(attr.nodeName, attr.nodeValue);
});
newScriptEl.innerHTML = pseudoScript.text;
document.body.append(newScriptEl);

pseudoScript.remove();
```

Any better ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A small solution with `appendChild` instead of `insertAdjacentHTML`:

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
var scriptCode = document.createTextNode("document.write('hello')");
scriptElement.appendChild(scriptCode); 

document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Comment: @Larmia that's how 'document.write' works: it obliterates the entire document, see the documentation for this at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's more or less the best way to do it. What does it matter that it's "complicated"?

The only thing I't change is not to insert the original script into the "live" page, but into a separate element, which also has the advantage of not hard-coding the class name:

```
const scriptString = '<script class="heyo">document.write("hello")<\/script>';

const tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
tempDiv.innerHtml = scriptString;
const pseudoScript = tempDiv.firstChild;

const newScriptEl = document.createElement('script');
// ...
```